# Why can I no longer share a URL to Brave or Chrome?

Tags: chrome-for-android, android-10, share-menu, brave-browser

Within the last couple of months a change in Brave had affected my typical article reading workflow. This also affects Chrome, so I'm assuming it's a change in the underlying shared codebase.

I use [Pocket](https://getpocket.com/) to manage articles to read, and I would typically open an article in the Pocket app, click the share button, and then share the article URL to the browser. Recently this stopped working. Brave (and Chrome) no longer show in the list of all of the apps. Edge, however, does still show in that list.

I originally thought that Pocket had changed the way it was sharing, but I get the same results sharing a URL directly from one of the browser apps (though that app's *Print* action does show in the share options). Sharing from Pocket goes directly to the full app list, while sharing from the browser shows just the top options, then your have to scroll right and click *More…*.

My new workflow is to use the copy action (which includes the article title as well as URL), and then paste it into the browser, and then delete the article title so it's just the URL, then navigate.

Is there something I can configure to get this browser sharing feature back? Does anyone know what the underlying change was for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a couple of months, the Chrome share action returned, and then a couple of months later the Brave share action returned. I assume it was due to some changes in their apps.

[image: share dialog with Chrome and Brave, among others]

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Chrome, type: `chrome://flags/#chrome-sharing-hub`
2. Set it to Disable. Restart Chrome. After restarting, you will have the normal sharing sheet.

[image]

The process should be the same with Brave.

**Note:** Google may remove the flag in future releases of the app.

Comment: This changes the experience when sharing _from_ Brave, but doesn't seem to have any effect when trying to share _to_ Brave.